# Why keyword "include" is not working on bash

Tags: awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run on bash commands from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html content.

Trying to follow the below part, I created two scripts, and put in test2 the @include as instructed:

[image: extract from the manual]

After running $ gawk -f test2 I get the following error message:

$ awk -f test2

awk: test2:1: @include "test1" BEGIN { print "This is script test2." }

awk: test2:1: ^ invalid char '@' in expression

Please help me understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: Please post *your code*, not pictures of someone else's code.

Comment: from the error message it appears you haven't copied-n-pasted the code *exactly* as it appears at the www.gnu.org site; while this isn't necessarily a 'bad' thing it does raise the question of what exactly your script looks like (eg, the `@include "test1"` must a) reside on a line by itself *or* b) be terminated with a `;` if other code follows it on the same line); at this point it would be helpful if you could please update the question with the complete output from `head test1 test2`

Comment: also, please update the question with your `awk` version, eg, the complete output from `awk --version`

Comment: gawk(1) says Gawk has a too-large number of extensions to POSIX awk. They are described in ... and 'include' is among those extensions. But more likely there are some (visible or invisible) windows characters in those files.

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, I had different string written in my file, though it looks like the structure was OK, because switching to the updated version of awk solved the issue (the version that triggered my problem was GNU Awk 3.1.7). Thank you, I suppose that as long as your comment is not in the form of answer I cannot accept it.

Comment: @Drzemlik while I nudged you in the right direction you worked out the important details; feel free to post your own answer (to benefit others who come across this question in the future); fwiw, the `@include` (and `-i` and `--include`) was introduced with `gawk 4.1` (hence the reason your `gawk 3.1.7` was choking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for the problem was the gawk version being outdated.

As noticed by markp-fuso in comments:

"the @include (and -i and --include) was introduced with gawk 4.1 (hence the reason your gawk 3.1.7 was choking)."

Changing to the updated version of gawk solved my issue.